# Jquery Splitting string using Condition

Tags: jquery

I want to Split some variables using Jquery for example:

```
var a="a-b-c-d";

var b= "data-class.pg";

var c= 12/datas-put;
```

I want to remove the first (-) from that above datas  and my result look like

```
var a="b-c-d";
var b="class.pg";
var c="put";
```

I had use split operation but i don't know how to split the first specific (-) symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
a = a.substr(a.indexOf('-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to replace everything up to the first hyphen.

```
a = a.replace('/^.*?-/', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a.replace('/^[^-]+-/', '');
```